# Access file from StreamingAssets as an AudioClip Android - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an AudioClip from ".mp3" or ".wav" files that exists in the StreamingAssets folder

I'm trying to get a byte array from the file using BetterStreamingAssets package, then converting the array of bytes to audioClip, but many files arn't converted  correctly.

So, I tried to get it using WWW or UnityWebRequest so here is my code

```cs
public static IEnumerator PlayAudioClip(AudioSource audioSource, string path)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(path, AudioType.UNKNOWN))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        if (www.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            AudioClip myClip = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
            audioSource.clip = myClip;
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it like that

```
StartCoroutine(PlayAudioClip(audio, BetterStreamingAssets.Root + "/" + soundPath));
```

but what happen is the code working perfectly on editor or pc platform but on android platfrom no sound working.

So, how can I play the voice on android platform?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is the audio reproduction, or that the streamingassets path is different on android platform?

Comment: Can you include what the value of `BetterStreamingAssets.Root + "/" + soundPath` is ? the path to streaming assets is different for every build target. On android it is ` `"jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets"` `https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your path is in general correct totally depends on this `BetterStreamingAssets.Root` and `soundPath` ... you didn't show.

I just looked into the [Asset](https://github.com/gwiazdorrr/BetterStreamingAssets/tree/master/Assets/Plugins/BetterStreamingAssets) and it looks pretty unnecessary to me.

Simply use the correct and built-in [`Application.streamingAssetsPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html) which is always correct for the according target platform.

Also you are trying to access `BetterStreamingAssets.Root` which on android translates to

```c#
BetterStreamingAssets.ApkImpl.s_root
```

which is initialized with the `Application.dataPath` **not** the `Application.streamingAssetsPath`!

```c#
/*line 39*/ BetterStreamingAssetsImp.Initialize(Application.dataPath, Application.streamingAssetsPath);
```

which calls

```c#
/*line 341*/ public static void Initialize(string dataPath, string streamingAssetsPath)
```

where it sets

```c#
/*line 343*/ s_root = dataPath;
```

---

Also: **never** use simple string concat (`+ "/"`) for system file paths!

Rather use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) which inserts the correct path separators according to the storage system used by the device

```c#
StartCoroutine(PlayAudioClip(audio, Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, soundPath));
```

which - again - also depends pretty much on the `soundPath` ...

---

I'm also pretty sure you'll have to figure out and pass in the correct [`AudioType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioType.html) parameter to `UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip` according to your file-ending. Except it is indeed `3rd party / unknown plugin format.` in which case I kind of would not expect Unit being able to reproduce it.

---

**In general**

Is there a special reason at all why you want to read that audio from `StreamingAssets`?

Why not simply place it inside the assets and reference it somewhere so you can be sure it is definitely imported correctly? Or if you have multiple do e.g.

```c#
public class AudioDataController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource audioSource;

    [SerializeField] private AudioClip someClip;
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip someOtherClip;

    public void PlaySomeSound()
    {
        audioSource.clip = someClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

    public void PlayOtherSound()
    {
        audioSource.clip = someOtherClip;
        audioSource.Play();
    }
}
```

this way you wouldn't have that trouble at all I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually your response is very useful to me, the key was in Path.Combine trick instead of "/", so I realized that BetterStreamingAssets.GetFile() was working with me because they handled paths comination internly, so I'll not in need to this package any more, thanks.